# Python : One regular expression help

Tags: python, regex

In python, I've got a string like

```
ABC(a =2,bc=2, asdf_3 = None)
```

By using regular expression, I want to make it like

```
ABC(a =2,bc=2)
```

I want to remove the parameter that named 'asdf_3', that's it!

Update: The parameters can be a lot, only the asdf_3 is same in all cases, the order is usually the last one.

Comment: what have you learnt from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988632/python-use-regular-expression-to-remove-something

Comment: Please forget regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

foo = 'ABC(a =2,bc=2, asdf_3 = None)'
bar = re.sub(r',?\s+asdf_3\s+=\s+[^,)]+', '', foo)

# bar is now 'ABC(a =2,bc=2,)'
```

The `\s+` portions let you match any amount of whitespace, and the `[^,)]+` part lets it basically anything on the right-hand side that doesn't start another argument.

Comment: I need to get rid of the common after bar=2 as well.

Comment: That's what the `,?` at the beginning of the pattern is for.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing homework right? Show some effort on your part next time, since you already asked such questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988632/python-use-regular-expression-to-remove-something)

```
>>> foo.split("asdf_3")[0].strip(", ")+")"
'ABC(a =2,bc=2)'

>>> re.sub(",*\s+asdf_3.*",")",foo)
'ABC(a =2,bc=2)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that the `asdf_3` parameter is only *usually* the last one, I suggest the following:

```
result = re.sub(
    r"""(?x) # verbose regex
    ,?       # match a comma, if present
    \s*      # match spaces, if present
    asdf_3   # match asdf_3
    [^,)]*   # match any number of characters except ) or ,
    """, "", subject)
```

This assumes that commas can't be part of the argument after `asdf_3`, e. g. like `asdf_3 = "foo, bar"`.